# Proper way to traverse the dom with jquery and javascript and usage of "this"

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="tour" data-daily-price="357">
  <h2>Paris, France Tour</h2>
  <p>$<span id="total">2,499</span> for <span id="nights-count">7</span> Nights</p>
  <p>
    <label for="nights">Number of Nights</label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="number" id="nights" value="7">
  </p>
</div>
```

This is my incorrect code for changing the test of the span element to read what I typed into the number input.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#nights").on("keyup", function() {
    $("#nights-count").text($("#nights").val());
  });
});
```

This is the correct code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#nights").on("keyup", function() {
    $("#nights-count").text($(this).val());
  });
});
```

Why do I need to use self and not #nights for this to work?

Comment: do you have more than one element with id `#nights` ?

Comment: Both work fine with the HTML you have provided, most-likely you have duplicate id's as suggested above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work just fine unless `#nights` is not a unique ID. For example if there are multiple `"tour"` divs each having a `#nights` element. That said, `$(this)` is better because it doesn't require jQuery to go and parse the DOM again...

Answer (score 2):

> If you have multiple id with name `#nights` in your document then default it select first one id with id `#nights`. where `this` will indicating the current selected DOM element instead of `#nights` id. If you use `this` it indicate to current selected DOM element, that's why you get correct output in your case there is multiple id with `#nights`.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you have more than 1 element with the id `nights`. Your first block of code works: http://jsfiddle.net/fomd990c/

If you have another element with the id `nights` it doesn't: http://jsfiddle.net/fomd990c/1/

It is generally a good idea to restrict a particular id to only one element.